# Gap appears when zoom is 100%

Tags: css, less

I created codepen example to reproduce this case. I don't understand, why gap is. Above you can find a link to example

https://codepen.io/elena_serzh/pen/pojLdJY

[image]

```html
<section>
    <div class="al-timeline-wrapper">
        <div class="al-timeline first-circle">
            <div class="al-timeline-date-wrapper">
                <p>
                    date
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="al-text-wrapper">
                <p class="al-timeline-title">
                    title
                </p>
                <p class="al-timeline-description">
                    description info
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: can not reproduce with you codepen, seems fine.

Comment: I don't see any gap when I run the pen. In which browser you see it?

Comment: I agree. I don't see a problem, try it for different browsers

Comment: I use Chrome, gap appears when zoom is 100%